# In script base_url is not working why?

Tags: href, codeigniter-3, src, base-url

I use to write "`base_url`" in my header and footer files in CodeIgniter.
like

```
href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"
```

is working...

but when i write

```
src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"
```

is not working...

show my controller after `base_url` and the file is not linked then.

Why it is working in header and not working in footer although i have attached both files also.

Comment: can u show your full script code ? make sure u have loaded url helper

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Comment: thanks but i have sorted eariliar.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Load `url` helper (if not loaded), better use `autoload.php` like this :

```
$config['helper'] = array('url');
```

Use `site_url` in your `script` href, should be like this :

```
//here js is the folder name containing your js files

<script src="<?=site_url('js/yourjsfile.js');?>" ></script>
```

Comment: ya its ok you sorted it but what about the answer given here,pls check it as green it will encourage the users next time u will ask any question in future

Answer (score 0):

If you are using base_url frequently in your application then just go to application/config/autoload.php. Then modify  $config['helper']=array('url').
if you are using `base_url()` method in specific page then just add `$this->load->helper('url')` in your required method.

For more details you may read this `https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html`